# Implementing Single Sign On for Disqus in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, disqus

So I am currently using Disqus for my commenting system on my website It works perfectly but the downfall is that users need to have two accounts. One to access the site and another to comment!

Disqus offers SSO for this exact reason to allow a user to sign up only once (on the site) and automatically be given an 'in-app' disqus account to comment.

**The people at Disqus have activated SSO for me and have linked me to various documentation. I was wondering if there are any good tutorials/documentation to show you how to do this with rails?**

Comment: Have you looked at the Ruby example here? https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/sso/ruby/sso.rb

Comment: Thanks for this @RyanV ill have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

**disqus_rails gem - Disqus service RoR wrapper**

*acts_as_disquser and Single Sign On*

Disqus provides SSO service which gives ability to link your local users info to Disqus users, read more in Disqus tutorial. To do this, as and for linking model to Disqus thread - you have to add 'acts_as_disquser' line in your users model. You need pass there four attributes: 'id', 'username', 'email' and 'avatar'(avatar is an optional field, so you can omit this). Here is example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_disquser :username => :full_name, :email => :email, :avatar => Proc.new{ avatar.url }
  ...
end
```

As you see, you can pass there or symbols, or procs. First will try to get instance variable with such name from model's instance, second will evaluate code inside Proc with context of model's instance. Important - only Proc are available for second way of defining attribute, no lambdas. Also, you may not implicitly pass acts_as_disquser :id => :id - it will try to get id automatically if it is not defined. Next, you need to specify in disqus_init helper attributes 'disquser' with current user instance, and 'sso' as boolean to enable or disable SSO.

```
<%= disqus_init :disquser => current_user, :sso => true %>
```

After this is done, when users will post comments via Disqus, their username, email and avatar will be taken from your site.

https://github.com/sandric/disqus_rails